# Python: Execute while waiting for network data

Tags: python

Newbie to Python, is there a way to execute python command(s)/script while waiting for another command to execute such as waiting for recv command to get data from network? is that something poll command could do?

TIA

Comment: Use thread, multiprocessing, or asyncio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `asyncio` module and its functions, specifically `loop.sock_recv` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.sock_recv)

Comment: is it possible to use socket library with asyncio? i tried using `await sock.recv(1024)` but it gives error. I think i need to the asyncio version of socket functions right?

Comment: Right, functions from standard library are synchronous.

Comment: Also, is it possible to read file while some task is being executed asynchronously like waiting for an response from network? I was trying to use [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28057308/check-if-a-file-is-modified-in-python) but i guess this will not work because its not async.

Comment: It depends on task what you want to solve.

Comment: You can run file reading in another coroutine and read file by chunks with small asyncio.sleep for example. Sleep is required to switch between coroutines